# Python selenium: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Today I got this message on the console when running selenium using the chromedriver. How do I suppress this?

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12740/devtools/browser/97101fe4-3b1f-42b0-b5c8-373cc18040b6
```

Relevant code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:/bin/chromedriver233')
```

I get the same message using version 2.30 of chromedriver.

I have not previously received this message. The only change I've made is updating chrome to Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Python 3.6.3 64, selenium 3.4.3, Windows 7 64.

EDIT: I posted a question to the Chrome product forum at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Dlk2j_JpmxE;context-place=forum/chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome devmode suddenly turning on in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423361/chrome-devmode-suddenly-turning-on-in-selenium)

Answer (score 65):

I had the same issue, did a bit of digging and finally found a working solution. This should remove the `DevTools` message popping up:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
```

As per the solution from [this chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2907#c3).

Comment: If you are using C#, use:     `code`options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-logging");`code`

Comment: I'm trying this in 9/29/22 and this is not working. Other attempts such as: options.add_argument('--log-level=3')    
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')  ; Did not work as well

Comment: For future googlers, executable_path is now deprecated, instead you can put the chromedriver in the chrome install path and just omit the executable_path parameter. Everything else in the answer is still the same

Comment: As at 03 May '23, this works great | chromedriver\win32\112.0.5615.49 using `webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware but [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423361/chrome-devmode-suddenly-turning-on-in-selenium):

```
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
```

Mind you I'm using headless, though I believe you could configure this for normal browser.  It feels better :).  I was amazed at how annoying that notification message was.

Comment: Alas, that didn't help, I still got the message.

Comment: @foosion Did you try what I referenced with the link word for word, it works for me.

Comment: @foosion This is likely attributed to new chrome.  I have done a fresh reinstall and I cannot get it to work either.  Interesting, this command used to work.  I wonder why

Comment: @foosion I am curious to ask them but I can't comment as I'm not 50.  Ask them if updating chrome gave issue.  Otherwise there's something I'm missing

Comment: @ tyson dogerzonda I believe it was updating to the latest chrome that caused the problem, as it was working fine last week and that was my only change.

Who should I ask?

Comment: @foosion I'm not sure either.  I've tried suppressing console output, cmd.  But I believe it's likely a chrome issue.  So perhaps try using older chrome but that's not really viable long term either.  I suppose you'll have to just put up with it.  There might be a way to get around it through chrome options but I cannot find much on this issue.  I believe its a new issue so not much to find

Comment: with luck they'll fix selenium or the chromedriver

Comment: @foosion I should hope so.  Maybe report it on chrome forums and I'm sure there's some out there who knows how to fix this.  Just a matter of asking question to right person I guess or building a tolerance to annoying messages.  Whichever works :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue with 64.0.3282.186. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to chromedriver no longer supports chrome version installed on your machine. Update your Chromedriver to more up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the second and third lines to your code and you should be able to see the devtools messages in your command prompt.

`chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions() chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitch',['enable-logging']) chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3') driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path_of_chrome-driver>', options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score -5):

a workaround: :)

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
```