# nodejs Windows: How to hide output messages from selenium-webdriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

using selenium-webdriver in this setting, how do i hide this message?

`DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61999/devtools/browser/325a03f2-f33c-4b3c-af13-518adb474d9a`

setup:

- Windows 10 x64
- node-v14.9.0-win-x64
- selenium-webdriver + mocha + puppeteer in **async** mode

i tried this:

- --log-level=1 2 3 4
- adding all the options below to Builder.withCapabilities()
- mocha.cmd >NUL 2>&1
- read all of stackexchange about that subject

code i use in the test.js:

````
const { Builder, By, Key, until, _ } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
var options = new chrome.Options().setChromeBinaryPath('x:\\path\\chrome.exe');
    options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
    options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=0");
    
    options.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
    options.addArguments("--allow-outdated-plugins");
    options.addArguments("--disable-logging");
    options.addArguments("--disable-breakpad");
    options.addArguments("--disable-client-side-phishing-detection");
    options.addArguments("--disable-component-update");
    options.addArguments("--disable-hang-monitor");
    options.addArguments("--disable-prompt-on-repost");
    options.addArguments("--disable-web-resources");
    options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update");
    options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
    options.addArguments("--use-mock-keychain");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--metrics-recording-only");
    
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests");
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("--no-first-run");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("--silent");
    options.addArguments("--ignore-gpu-blacklist");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--disable-software-rasterizer");
    options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(browserName).withCapabilities(options).build();```
````

Answer (score 2):

This post [from stack][1] and some help from a Nodejs expert helped me find out the solution!! It looks like the default startup flags / options for ChromeDriver changed, and Selenium hasn't really documented that one of them (*enable-logging*) **overrides** logging preferences that you set through Selenium options.

```
// 1] do not add any of those logging options to the driver:
// options.addArguments("--disable-logging-redirect")
// options.addArguments("--enable-logging=stderr")
// options.addArguments("--disable-and-delete-previous-log")
// options.addArguments("--disable-logging");

// 2] add this one:
options.excludeSwitches('enable-logging');

// and finally:
driver = new Builder().forBrowser(browserName).withCapabilities(options).build();
```

And voila, no logging anymore of any of those pesky messages:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61015/devtools/browser/f4376b68-a497-41cf-a912-f0c3b5ca3a61
[23624:25384:0908/192940.145:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[1376:15316:0819/194612.952:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [19:46:12.951] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1164 RequestRadioAccessAsync failed: RadioAccessStatus::DeniedByUserWill not be able to change radio power.
```

[1]: [Python selenium: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392423/python-selenium-devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-1))

Comment: That didn't work for me.