# Disable "DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1..." log message in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm using the SeleniumLibrary in Robot Framework to test a web application. My test project is currently using only `.robot` files, with no python code in it, and I wanted to disable this ChromeDriver log message, which appears after every test case in the console log.

I'm currently using:

- Chromedriver **v88**
- Google Chrome **v88.0.4324**
- SeleniumLibrary **v3.0.0**
- Robot Framework **v3.2.2**

Here is the full log message:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62913/devtools/browser/569eba7c-49ea-4fa7-953a-dee9730b3157
```

Apparently it's possible to solve it when using python code to do it, as we have in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392423/python-selenium-devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-1).
But since I'm doing everything with only Robot Framework files, I want to continue this way.

I've also read the [SeleniumLibrary Documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html) searching for some solution, but found nothing useful for this case.

Useful Code - Library import:

```
Library     SeleniumLibrary     run_on_failure=Nothing
```

Is there any options to disable this log message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer you have linked this is what you need:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Silent Chrome
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com    Chrome    options=add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

From the [`Open Browser`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) keyword's documentation:

> The string format allows defining Selenium options methods or
> attributes and their arguments in Robot Framework test data. The
> method and attributes names are case and space sensitive and must
> match to the Selenium options methods and attributes names. When
> defining a method, it must be defined in a similar way as in python:
> method name, opening parenthesis, zero to many arguments and closing
> parenthesis. If there is a need to define multiple arguments for a
> single method, arguments must be separated with comma, just like in
> Python. Example: `add_argument("--headless")` or
> `add_experimental_option("key", "value")`.