# How to resolve this error in Selenium : ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE, ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser, certificate

I'm trying to execute a selenium program in Python to go to a new URL on click of a button in the current homepage. I'm new to selenium and any help regarding this would be appreciated. Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://nmit.ac.in'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

try:
    # wait 10 seconds before looking for element
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(By.LINK_TEXT, "Parent Portal")
    )

except:
    print()

driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Parent Portal").click()
```

I have tried to increase the wait time as well as using all forms of the supported located strategies under the `BY` keyword, but to no avail. I keep getting this error.
[image: Error photo]

Answer (score 5):

A lot of time passed while I was looking for a solution and I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408800/21104234).

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service= Service(chromedriver_path), 
    options=options,
)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

It should remove all annoying errors and warnings from selenium

Comment: Ahh, fixing the error by ignoring it :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you shouldn't be worried by those errors. Although, I proved your code and it's not finding any element in the web page. I can recommend you use the xpath of the element you want to find:

```
    # wait 10 seconds before looking for element
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html//div[@class='wsmenucontainer']//button[@href='https://nmitparents.contineo.in/']"))
    )   
    element.click()
    #wait for the new view to be loaded
    time.sleep(10)  
    driver.quit()
```

Psdt: you can use the extention Ranorex Selocity to extract a good and unique xpath of any element in a webpage and also test it!!
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFt1i.png)

Comment: It's working for me when I ignored those errors like you said, seemingly it just takes time for the website to respond to the click or for selenium to click.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around it using:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) # Here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
```

Microsoft Edge:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) # Here
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
```

Firefox. *`FirefoxOptions()` doesn't have `add_experimental_option()`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.accept_untrusted_certs = True # Here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
```