# Cannot disabe DevTools listening on ws in chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I am getting this message and previously used the accepted solution here:
[Chrome devmode suddenly turning on in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423361/chrome-devmode-suddenly-turning-on-in-selenium)

Previously this worked for me.  Upon reinstall however, I have noticed this no longer works.

SO for example:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
```

To see output in Cmd go:

pyinstaller -F AVA.py.

Run exe.

Run that.  And you'll notice that the message [appears](https://ibb.co/gxwbOR).  Previously this solution worked.  I believe this could be because of new chrome or that that answer simply does not answer that question and there was some element missing for this to be a full solution.

Anyone know how to remove this message through chrome preferences.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Add these two options.

```
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('test-type')
```

Comment: Had no effect for me, message still is displayed